# POJOs declaration for different api with common fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I need to create response POJOs class for a couple of APIs i have to call in my microservice . The  response has a base structure given below.

```
{
    "requestId": "abcd-1234-3456",
    "sourceSystem": "HOME",
    "response": {
        "statusCode": "200",
        "statusMessage": "Successfully Received",
        "statusType": "SUCCESS",
        "details": [
            {
             "message" : "hi"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here the object inside the "details" property array can vary and can have different class definitions. Can someone help whether how should i declare my POJOs so that there is a common class for the common fields and a different set of classes for object inside details property . I tried few ways using java generics and @JsonSubType but that is giving some error  `Unrecognized field "details"` during deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try and define it as object instead :-

```
class Response{
 private String requestId;
 private String statusMessage;
 private String statusType;
 private List<Object> details;
 }
```

Comment: How will i tell jackson mapper for the defination of Object?